# Sens de « saisie semi-automatique » ?

Tags: sens, informatique, terminologie

Dans cette phrase:

> Concrètement, les lignes d'OD (ordres de déménagement) sont entrées
>   manuellement avec une saisie semi-automatique grâce au connecteur SAP.

que Google Translate traduit :

> Specifically, the DO (moving orders) lines are entered manually with
>   AutoComplete with the SAP connector.

l'expression « saisie semi-automatique » veut-elle dire « semi-automatic input  », ou « auto-complete », ou peut-elle être employée pour les deux ?

Plus précisément, est-ce que « saisie semi-automatique » pour « auto-complete » est une traduction précise/usuelle, ou dirait-on plutôt « auto-complétion », auquel cas « saisie semi-automatique » signifierait plutôt « pre-inputted » ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compte-tenu que "to complete" a un sens un peu plus fort que "compléter", à savoir vraiment mener à terme, achever, si j'ose dire "*achever complètement*", il y a une très légère nuance.

"Saisie semi-automatique" signifie plutôt que la machine propose un choix, il suffit de cliquer dans une liste.

"Auto-complétion" : hmm, je préférerais "complétude", terme qui existe en maths, signifie plutôt que lorsque l'on a commencé à saisir un mot, la machine propose le choix le plus probable, complète donc, tente d'achever, jusqu'à ce qu'il n'y ait plus qu'une seule possibilité, ou que l'on soit d'accord avec la proposition.

Comment: En fait, l'auto-complétion propose un choix, c'est-à-dire une saisie semi-automatique. Je dirais que la saisie semi-automatique inclut l'auto-complétion mais est plus générale (listes déroulantes, évolution de la présentation du formulaire selon les saisies déjà réalisées, préremplissage du formulaire selon les informations déjà connues par l'ordinateur...).

Comment: La complétude n’a rien à voir avec la complétion : la [complétion](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/complétion), c’est l’action de compléter. La [complétude](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/complétude), c’est le caractère d’être complet.

Answer (score 8):

Les expressions "auto-complétion" ou "saisie semi-automatique" sont des traductions courantes de l'expression anglaise "auto-complete", dans un contexte informatique.
Elles sont, à ma connaissance, utilisées de façon équivalente.